# How does regex capture groups work on this particular log statement

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have constructed the regex for the below log statement and trying to add capture groups so that I can assign each group to a variable and print them. I am getting null values when I added parentheses as capture blocks. Is there away I can add capture groups to below regex.

Log:

> `2022-02-09 10:00:52,785 EST|2022-02-09 10:00:52.785 CST 48767a165b22 [INFO ] CorrelationId=d0b0005a-56aa-4e23-a00e-7b22bc41d001 ApplicationName=ATSystems [http-nio-8080-exec-8] com.jivasciences.jrx.mo.bundle.app.transform.handler.bundleHandler - ReceivedDate=2022-02-09 10:00:56`

from which I want to capture the following as groups:

- `48767a165b22`
- `INFO`
- `d0b0005a-56aa-4e23-a00e-7b22bc41d001`
- `ATSystems`
- `com.jivasciences.jrx.mo.bundle.app.transform.handler.bundleHandler`
- `2022-02-09 10:00:56`

My regex so far:

> `([0-9]+(-[0-9]+)+) [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?,[0-9]+ [a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} (([+-]?(?=\.\d|\d)(?:\d+)?(?:\.?\d*))(?:[eE]([+-]?\d+))?(:([+-]?(?=\.\d|\d)(?:\d+)?(?:\.?\d*))(?:[eE]([+-]?\d+))?)+) [a-zA-Z]+ ([0-9]+([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)+) \[[^\]]*] CorrelationId=[{]?[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-([0-9a-fA-F]{4}-){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12}[}]? ApplicationName=[a-zA-Z]+ \[[^\]]*] [a-zA-Z]+(\.[a-zA-Z]+)+ - ReceivedDate=([0-9]+(-[0-9]+)+) ([0-9]+(:[0-9]+)+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[0-9 ,.:-]+ [A-Z]{3}\|[0-9 ,.:-]+ [A-Z]{3} ([0-9a-f]+) \[(\w+) *].*?=([0-9a-f-]+).*?=(\w+).*?\] ([\w.]+).*?=([0-9-]+ [0-9:]+)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/ecR3QbqwfUfjLD).

---

More readable format:

> `[0-9 ,.:-]+ [A-Z]{3}\|[0-9 ,.:-]+ [A-Z]{3} ([0-9a-f]+) \[(\w+) *].*?=([0-9a-f-]+).*?=(\w+).*?\] ([\w.]+).*?=([0-9-]+ [0-9:]+)`

Answer (score 0):

This pattern should do it.

```
^.*?\|.*?\s(\w{9,})\s\[([A-Z]+).*?CorrelationId=\{?([a-f0-9-]{36})\}?\sApplicationName=(.*?)\s\[.*?\]\s(\S+)\s-\sReceivedDate=([\d\-]{10}\s[\d:]{8}).*$
```

The first part is simplified, since those timestamps aren't required.

Test on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Qv3bYP/1)